# How to add thousands separator to string value which may contain floating points

Tags: c#

I have a string series of values which may or may not contain a floating point number. I want to add the thousands separator to this numeric string. I want to have the value with thousands separators and floating point number only when it's there. How can I do this?

Examples:

```
Input:  23456.78
Output: 23,456.78

Input:  23456
Output: 23,456
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try parsing to `decimal` (or `double`) and then *format back* to the required representation (`"#,#.##########"` format string in your case):

```
String input = "23456.78";

// 23,456.78
String output = decimal
 .Parse(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
 .ToString("#,#.##########", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, The only problem with your answer is that when i try to input "5754289" and it returns "5754289.00". But i don't need the floating point part with it.

Comment: @Dinukshi Jayarathne: if you don't want `.00` and alike floating point, then format string should be something like `"#,#.##########"` (see my edit)